# StageXl and Dart

Tags: dart, stagexl

When I use StageXL I get this warning:

> Element 'MouseEvent' from SDK library 'html_dartium.dart' is implicitly hidden by 'stagexl.dart'

I haven't found any info on why it appears and if it gives problems, but I think it might be the reason I have issues with my code somewhere else (I'm using a MouseEvent on a onClick event listener for a button)

Is there a way to distinguish the use of both MouseEvents?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usually you solve such conflicts with import aliases like

```dart
import 'dart:html' as dom;
import 'package:stagexl/stagexl.dart' as sxl;
```

then you reference members of the libraries like

```dart
dom.MouseEvent
sxl.MouseEvent
```

If that doesn't solve your problem some code would be helpful to see what you try and how.

Comment: Unfortunately Flash and HTML have some classes with the same name but different fields. Therefore the StageXL Samples always imports the dart:html library "as html" and the StageXL library without an alias. In most use cases you don't need the html-classes when you work with StageXL, so it should be okay.

Comment: I'm creating an application with a GUI (html classes?) with StageXL to manage the graphical effects in it. I might be using the wrong library, but I'm experimenting and so far I think I should use StageXL to draw on canvas and html for everything else.

Comment: @mobinoob I'm not sure if your comment is a question. I can't help you anyway I guess, because I don't know StageXL at all, I only recognized the Error `... implicitly hidden by ...`.

Comment: No question (yet), I was just explaining to bp74 why I am using both libraries. I might post a question later, but as a separate post. thanks!